# does vscode-server serve-local not persist configuration?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm running vscode's new code-server *(https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/vscode-server)* locally in a vm, and it seems to treat every unique browser session as a new instance *(vs. persist configuration and customization on the server)*

is this an intended functionality? I can't seem to find any documentation on this anywhere!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User settings are stored locally (in a browser local storage), so for convenience I moved most of my configuration to Machine settings file.

It can be accessed via "Preferences: Open remote settings (JSON)"
Or remotely via ~/.vscode-server/data/Machine/settings.json

Note that not all user settings can be moved to Machine config (watch for greyed out lines).

Comment: nice, did not know about Remote Settings, thanks for the tip!